# How to align <apex:inputField> with CSS?

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, inputfield

I am styling `<apex:>` tags with CSS but can't seem to align the inputFields correctly as they won't respond to `padding`, `float:`, or `margin:`.

[image]

VF Snippet

```
<!-- Form starts -->
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Recipient Information" columns="2" id="recipient">
    <apex:outputLabel value="First Name" styleClass="inputLabel">
        <apex:inputField value="{!rec.Name}" styleClass="inputField"/>
    </apex:outputLabel>
```

CSS

```
.inputField {
    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: grey;
    width: 300px;
}

.inputLabel {
    font-family: Salesforce Sans Regular;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `<apex:outputLabel>`. `<apex:inputField>` automatically renders a label for you. If you need to override the label, you can use the `label` property on the `<apex:inputField />`.

Comment: Yes but when overriding the CSS of the inputField with `styleClass` the label disappears... besides that I cannot seem to align the `inputFields`

Comment: @SpicyPat You can also use apex:pageBlockSectionItem to force two columns. This may help.